# SharePoint Online LookUp field PATCH call

Tags: ajax, rest, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

The problem I am having is when I make a PATCH call to the SharePoint LookUp field. Every time I make the call all the Id´s already in the multivalue lookup column gets overwritten. My temporary fix is to retrieve all Id´s in the LookUp field and then add the new Id to the array that contains all the existing Id´s and then make the PATCH call with that array . Shouldn't the PATCH call just add the new id to the LookUp field without erasing the already existing Ids in the field? This problem feels tricky to explain. Hope I am clear enough. Thanks for all the help!

The code:

```
    function linkContract(ajaxData) {

            var def = jQuery.Deferred();
            //Url
            var url = `${_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Avtal')/items('${window._cache.avtalsInfoId}')`;

            //requestHeaders
            var requestHeaders = {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-HTTP-Method": "PATCH",
                "IF-MATCH": `${window._cache.avtal_eTag}`,
                "X-RequestDigest": jQuery('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
            }
          //Array with old Id´s that I add the new Id to and then PATCH it to the column     
 window._cache.relateradeAvtalArray.push(parseInt(ajaxData.RelateradeAvtalId));

            //Data
            var data = {
                __metadata: {
                    "type": "SP.Data.AvtalItem"
                },
                RelateradeAvtalId: {
                    'results': window._cache.relateradeAvtalArray//<--Array with old and new id´s
                },

            };
            //requestBod
            var requestBody = JSON.stringify(data);

            //Post
            var postLookId = jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "PATCH",
                headers: requestHeaders,
                data: requestBody
            });

            //Done
            postLookId.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                def.resolve(data);


            });
            //Fail
            postLookId.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            })
            return def.promise();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PATCH` method allows partial updates of entities but not properties of entity, in another words properties specified in *request payload* will be replaced while entity's current state will be preserved.

For example, with the following request

```
Url: /_api/web/lists/getbytitle(Tasks)/items(1)
Method. POST
Headers: {"Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose","Content-Type":"application/json; odata=verbose","X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE","If-Match":"\"36\"","X-RequestDigest":"0x6B24D8B9C10F251812478A2D313EBD36D5373993A11CF9EF1D8414555C5E1CC1D0AD596633E2AEF4D5194CB534CF25006C913BDEC885F6914B4D2803DAB6FC04,27 Jan 2018 13:17:32 -0000"}
Data: {"__metadata":{"type":"SP.Data.TasksListItem"},"PredecessorsId":{"__metadata":{"type":"Collection(Edm.Int32)"},"results":[3]}}
```

the `Predecessors` field value will be *replaced* in existing list item resource of Tasks list

To *merge* Lookup field value you could consider the following solution:

- submit get query to retrieve existing list item
- update field value by merging an existing lookup ids and new ones on the client
- submit update query to update list item resource

Comment: I already solved my problem with your Update solution. But thank you for taking time to answer the question.

Comment: Or to be precise. I did a merge